# Hadoop removing a mount point folder from Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, removeall

I've searched and I've been reading on Cloudera Hadoop on removing mount point file systems but I cannot find a thing on removing them.

I have two SSD drives in 6 machines and when I initially installed Cloudera Hadoop it added all file systems and I only need two mount points to run a few teragen and terasorts.

I need to remove everything except for:
/dev/nvme0n1 and /dev/nvme1n1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloudera Manager you can modify the list of drives used for HDFS data at:

Clusters > HDFS > Configuration > DataNode Default Group (or whatever you may have renamed this to) > DataNode Data Directory